# CoreMotion - magneticField is always 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-motion

I'm trying to use magnetometer:

```
[myMotionMngr startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue: [NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                  withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) 
{
    printf("%f\t%f\t%f\n", motion.magneticField.field.x, motion.magneticField.field.y, motion.magneticField.field.z);
    CMMagneticFieldCalibrationAccuracy acc = motion.magneticField.accuracy;
}];
```

And the filed (x,y,z) is always 0. 
`motion.magneticField.accuracy` is always *CMMagneticFieldCalibrationAccuracyUncalibrated*. According to docs it means that my device has got no magnetometer, however it is no true cause I'm testing on iPad2 with iOS 5.0.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just in case try [Teslameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Teslameter/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code.

Comment: @rokjarc Teslameter uses Core Location and not Core Motion.

Comment: @oops, sorry for that. glad to see you solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:toQueue:withHandler:

it should work

Comment: The problem was so simple, I can't believe it. Thank you!