# swift get CalibratedMagneticField is always zero

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift4, ios12

I try use iphone to get CalibratedMagneticField(in geo-coordinate).But is always  retrun 0 .(another SO question :CoreMotion - magneticField is always 0:[CoreMotion - magneticField is always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556859/coremotion-magneticfield-is-always-0)).
my version is swift4+ios12.
here is my code

```
func myacc(){
                motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.5
                motion.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = true
                motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in
                    print(data as Any)
                if let trueData = data {
                    self.view.reloadInputViews()

                    let x = trueData.magneticField.field.x
                    let y = trueData.magneticField.field.y
                    let z = trueData.magneticField.field.z



                    self.xAccel.text = String(x)
                    self.yAccel.text = String(y)
                    self.zAccel.text = String(z)
                    }

            }
```

Comment: Hi @mag. Have you tried using `motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(usingReferenceFrame:to:handler:)` as suggested in the linked post?

Comment: thank you very much,now i have resolved it ,by using  motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.xArbitraryCorrectedZVertical, to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error)  in print(data as Any)

Comment: Glad you resolved it